# Puppet node does not pull changes from master

Tags: linux, ubuntu, puppet

I have followed the following three How-To's

`http://terokarvinen.com/2012/puppetmaster-on-ubuntu-12-04`

`https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/puppet.html#puppet-installation`

`http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/install_puppet/post_install.html`

I get to the point of being able to start the puppet node, and on the master using `puppet cert --list` seeing the certificate and accepting it using `cert --sign`

However passed this point the node does not pick up the changes from the master. The master has the following node:

```
   include apache2
```

And the following manifest:

```
package {
    'apache2':
        ensure => installed
}

service {
    'apache2':
        ensure => true,
        enable => true,
        require => Package['apache2']
}
```

I have restarted `puppet` and `puppetmaster` multiple times as well as let the servers sit all weekend and still the node has not installed `apache2` onto itself.

**EDIT:**

Using `puppet master --verbose -no-daemonize` I receive the following:

```
root@puppetmaster:/etc/puppet/manifests# puppet master --verbose -no-daemonize
Error: Could not intialize global default settings: Error parsing arguments
Wrapped exception:
invalid argument syntax: '--'
```

Using `puppet agent --test --noop' I receive the following:

```
root@puppet:/var/log/puppet# puppet agent --test --noop
Notice: Skipping run of Puppet configuration client; administratively disabled (Reason: 'Disabled by default on new installations');
Use 'puppet agent --enable' to re-enable.
```

Comment: Can you post the `puppet` log from the node and `puppetmaster` log from the master?

Comment: @BelminFernandez funny thing is, in `/var/log/puppet` which is where the config has stated to place the logs there are none.

Comment: Sorry about that, forgot that it's two leading dashes in front of `--no-daemonize`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you do not have logs. I would stop `puppetmaster` on the master server then run it this way:

```
puppet master --verbose --no-daemonize
```

On the node server, stop `puppet` service and run it verbose with `noop`:

```
puppet agent --test --noop
```

This should give you some output that will hopefully help troubleshooting.

My guess: Certificate issues. It usually is with `puppet`.

Comment: Please see my EDITS in my original question.

Comment: That worked, I now got `Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Service[apache2]: Could not evaluate: Could not find init script or upstart conf file for 'apache2'` finally an error to go off!

Comment: How is `puppetmaster` working? Can you re-run the first command I point to and paste output? Once we got that working fine. We could move on to `puppet` node.

Comment: Puppetmaster is currently in verbose mode and I can see all it's output.

Comment: Okay, so when you run `puppet` command above, what do you get? Same issue?

Comment: You're help allowed me to get an error output, which allowed me to solve the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The output from `puppet agent` that you added to the bottom of your question spells it out:

> Notice: Skipping run of Puppet configuration client; administratively disabled (Reason: 'Disabled by default on new installations');
>
> Use 'puppet agent --enable' to re-enable.

It doesn't get any clearer than that.